# how to convert an image from index to rgb color usinh matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rgb

how to convert an image from index to rgb color usinh matlab? I have previously converted it to rgb to index but when I use `ind2rgb()` to convert it back to rgb, nothing is changed in image.

Answer (score 0):

```
%matmap2rgb
%converts a MxN matrix, and a Lx3 matrix to MxNx3 matrix
%syntax: matmap2rgb(mat, map);
function outrgbmat=matmap2rgb(mat, map)
rowVect=map(mat+1,:);
outrgbmat(:,:,1)=reshape(rowVect(:,1),size(mat,1),size(mat,2));
outrgbmat(:,:,2)=reshape(rowVect(:,2),size(mat,1),size(mat,2));
outrgbmat(:,:,3)=reshape(rowVect(:,3),size(mat,1),size(mat,2));
end
```